# Installing SDK 6.0 for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am trying to do the settings in Eclipse for Blackberry SDK 6.0.

Every time it gives me strange errors; earlier it was giving me error like "Unable to read repository". Then I opened there firewall and tried to install again. Now it's giving me error like "An Error occured while provisioning". I am really not understanding what should I do to solve this problem.

I have already installed the eclipse plugin "BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.1.2.201004161203-16".I am following the steps given at following link "http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12794/BlackBerry_Java_Plug-in-Installation_and_Configuration_Guide--933891-1125035846-001-1.1-US.pdf"

How can I solve my problem regarding doing the settings for SDK 6.0 in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest Java® Plug-in for Eclipse® v1.3 (updated on Dec. 23, 2010). From RIM's [web page](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp), it says that it includes support for the SDK v6.0. All of the [documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry+Java+Plug-in+for+Eclipse+%28Win%29) was updated recently as well.